# Handle Layout in io5 and ios 6 without using two xibs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

How can i handle Layout in IOS5 as well as IOS6.Previously i have developed my application in IOS5.Now i am facing problem of layout (3.5 and 4 inch). i have done ot of of r & d and found that we can solve it using constraints but i don't understand concept of constraints. Can any one help me to do so without using two xibs?
i found [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2)

How do I move ahead, but at the same time provide backwards compatibility? Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411980/enabling-auto-layout-in-ios-6-while-remaining-backwards-compatible-with-ios-5

Comment: @iCrazyDev for that i have to create two different xibs

Answer (score 2):

Don't use AutoLayout because your iOS5 users won't even be able to run your app. Keep "Use Autolayout" unchecked in Interface Builder. Instead, use springs and struts in IB or your views' `autoresizingMask` property in code.

Comment: Do you have any code or reference link to set autoresizingMask through code or xib ?

Comment: Here's a good summary from another stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468389/uiview-autoresizingmask-interface-builder-to-code-programmatically-create-st

Comment: The answer would be even nicer with some code. Also it would get an up-vote from me ;-) As it is now it is not a complete answer.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson The question was specifically about AutoLayout in *xib files*, so there is no sample code. I already linked another thread if you do want to do it in code.

Comment: @erurainon Sorry I missed that part (>//<)