# Autoresizing Not Working Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard, autoresizingmask

I want to create a `UIView` which will resize it's width according to iPhone Screen size and it should be remain at bottom of view.

I created fresh project with storyboard and add below code.

Here is my code

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:true];

    UIView *box = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 448, 320, 120)];
    [box setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [box setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [box setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [box setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
    [box setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
    [box setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];

    [self.view addSubview:box];
}
```

Auto layout is OFF.

If I do same thing by apply autoresizing from interface builder then it's working perfectly.

I didn't understand any reason for why it's not working.

Comment: More info here: [UIView autoresizingMask - Interface Builder to Code - Programmatically create struts and springs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468389/uiview-autoresizingmask-interface-builder-to-code-programmatically-create-st)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little mistake from my side.
My code is correct.

The issue is related to xCode 6.1, in launch screen we have xib file from xCode 6 so i have to remove reference of it from General Setting-> App Icon and Launch Images and use Assert Catalog instead of launchscreen.xib and it start working....

Anyway thanks for reply to my question.

Answer (score 3):

from

```
http://stackoverflow.com/q/7754851/4030971
```

Setting only (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight) is equivalent to:

[image]

Setting (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin) in code is equivalent to:

[image]

i think -

you need to set only flexible width and flexible bottom hence its effecting reverse. don't use flexible height. if you need to use flexible height then instead of assigning flexible top with flexible width assign flexible width, flexible height and flexible bottom. so it will remove top one. see assigning left right top bottom removing the corresponding if flexible width and flexible height is assigned. now you should do according. i think this will help.

Comment: its iphone 6 simulator. you are not using auto layout. you need to check self.view.frame.size.width and instead of 320 use the width of current view width.

Comment: Okey...
The scenario is I create the box using interface builder and apply autosizing. It work perfect in all screen size. In this we define frame and autosizing also...
Now i want the same thing to happen programmatically. where i define frame and autosizing

Comment: you can check above comment

Comment: and yes AUTO LAYOUT Is DISABLE

Comment: if you want to add a view which will aligned to bottom and take full width of the main screen then you need to set the width of the frame same as your main screen and the flexible width is not required. no resizing will be required. in case of bottom align you need to just set the bottom margin.

Comment: UIView *box = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-120, self.view.frame.size.width, 120)];
[box setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];    no need of any sizing.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting all of your resizing masks.

You can do it like this:

```
[box setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a mask, try do this:

```
[box setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
```

- also, if you want the height wont change, remove `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`

**edit**

To set it for any device size do something like this:

```
CGRect fr = box.frame;
fr.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
fr.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - 120;
box.frame = fr;
```

Comment: Can you describe what do you see? I did a simple test and it worked for me.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byb4VeRBzTKvY0ZqOEpOOEh6WWM/view?usp=sharing

You can check out this screen shot...

Comment: Ok, so it's because iPhone6 has bigger screen size than your box frame. See my edit answer

Comment: That's correct... but i would like to user autoresizing as it is working through interface builder but not programmatically ..

Comment: What do you mean? Did you see my edit in the answer? you have to set the width and origin y as your screen size...

Comment: I know i can implement this way as you wrote... but autoresizing can also do this from interface builder....
I would like to use autoresize programmatically instead of setting frame.
I am clearing my concepts for autoresizing ... that's why i would like to use autoresizing through coding.