# Any other method to resize views, other than Auto-layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, autoresizingmask

I am building an app, exclusively for iPhones and it only has a Portrait view. I have never used autolayout before and I don't think I have time to learn it now. Can I use anything else, to have my views resize themselves for the devices(iphone 4s, 5/5s, 6/6+)?

Comment: Information in this link may help you  -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468389/uiview-autoresizingmask-interface-builder-to-code-programmatically-create-st

Comment: You can manually set the size, and position for each view for all the iPhone sizes but that will be very tiring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the autolayout and sizeclasses

[image]

And use autoresizing form utilities

[image]

You can also do it by code :

```
view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |    
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin);
```