# How can I make UITextField always centered on the screen?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I'm making an app in which I add people to a list by using a modal VC, that currently has only three text fields.

**Problem:**
This is what I see in the interface builder, inside my Main.storyboard file:

[image]

I'm running Xcode version 6.2 (6C131e) and the app I'm making will be for iPod touch only, so I disabled auto-size classes. I'm expecting those text fields to be at the center of the screen (same distance from text field lateral border to screen edges). Instead I get this on the simulator:

[image]

**Question:**
How can I set an equal distance for both the sides of text fields? Any resource like tutorials, examples, guides are appreciated, because I am a very beginner in iOS programming. If this can be done with interface builder for me is better then programmatically.

Comment: check this.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837047/autolayout-complains-about-constraints-for-2-uitextfields-with-no-borders/30837324#30837324

Comment: You are using the autolayout or not?

Comment: I'm not using autolayout

Comment: @Johwhite I have added an answer for without autolayout hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you, now that i have your answer i better understand the differences between "autolayout" and "autoresize"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as this:

[image]

In the Align menu from the bottom of interface builder if you set this constraint to 0 it will be the center of the view

Comment: I accepted your answer because it's the most correct for the question. I tried to do only this and i obtain what i want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Select First Textfield

Goto Pin-> Uncheck constraints to Margin-> Select Top,Left,right constraints with default value(or change if want ex. 16 left,right,30 top).

For Second and Third Textfield
Goto Pin->Uncheck constraints to Margin->Select Top,Left,right constraints

Comment: If i simply do: pin>width
and: pin>height
It hasn't the same effect? The purpose of this is to give a precise  constraint to each textfield?

Comment: Yes you are right. then you have to apply align->Leading and trailing Edges constraints.but they will be in fixed width in landscape and iPad. hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Autolayout then the default Autoresizing property should be

[image]

Change the Autoresizing property to this :

[image]

Check this question : [Any other method to resize views, other than Auto-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252284/any-other-method-to-resize-views-other-than-auto-layout)

Comment: I was confused on what you asked about autolayout, because infact i'm using it in the project! Sorry for giving wrong informations! Thank you for the answer, it helps me the same.

Comment: @Johwhite Oh! you said I am not using autolayout. So, I have added this answer. Else other answers set constraint to Horizontal Center and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I just take horizontally as example. You have two ways to make it in the centre.
1. Make leading space equals trailing space.
[image]

2. Make the textfield center horizontally in container view.
   [image]

I recommend you can study with raywenderlich tutorial.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1