# How to Use Autoresize for a View in iOS Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autoresize

I've used Auto resize in Interface Builder and It's Works fine. But I want to know how to do that in programmatically. Because i want to change AutoResizing mask in ViewDidload according iPhone Series.

The Code I've used is given below:

```
_moreOptionsView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
```

I want to set Auto Resizing Mask to Width, Height, Right Margin & Top Margin through Programmatically.

Comment: possible duplicate :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468389/uiview-autoresizingmask-interface-builder-to-code-programmatically-create-st

Comment: where are you checking this?? few days back i was also doing the same then i found out that it works below iOS 7 not in iOS 8 and above. Why? i dont know but it may help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

You simple have to set the Autoresizing Mask of the view in question like so:

```
myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

This is achieved using the **Bitwise OR operator**. It will set all bits true that are true in either of both values provided.

Comment: I've also did the same. But Nothing Changes.

Answer (score -2):

Please check below link:

https://github.com/motion-kit/motion-kit/blob/master/lib/motion-kit-ios/helpers/uiview_autoresizing_helpers.rb

Help to you!