# IOS simple Visual Format layout doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm practicing with visual format layout using Objective-C & XCode 7 but struggling with getting a very simple layout to work. 
My app is just a simple Single View application and I'm trying to add a UILabel to main view.
Below is the code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = @"Hello world";
    label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    [self.view addSubview:label];

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label);
    [self.view addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[label]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
    [self.view addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[label]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];

    NSLog(@"constraints: %@", self.view.constraints);
}
```

Run this I got a bunch of errors:

```
    2016-02-01 18:14:15.729 AutolayoutVisualFormat[26671:909266] constraints: (
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x79771ab0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7976f950(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x79786d30 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7976f950]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79771790 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x797884e0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x79772e30(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x79777540 _UILayoutGuide:0x79772e30.bottom == UIView:0x79771790.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7978d930 H:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7976d000'Hello world']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79771790 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7978da50 H:[UILabel:0x7976d000'Hello world']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79771790 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7978fcb0 V:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7976d000'Hello world']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79771790 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7978fce0 V:[UILabel:0x7976d000'Hello world']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79771790 )>"
)
2016-02-01 18:14:15.733 AutolayoutVisualFormat[26671:909266] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a0630a0 h=--& v=--& H:[UILabel:0x7976d000'Hello world'(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7978d930 H:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7976d000'Hello world']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79771790 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7978da50 H:[UILabel:0x7976d000'Hello world']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79771790 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a080130 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x79771790(320)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7978da50 H:[UILabel:0x7976d000'Hello world']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79771790 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-02-01 18:14:15.733 AutolayoutVisualFormat[26671:909266] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a0758b0 h=--& v=--& V:[UILabel:0x7976d000'Hello world'(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7978fcb0 V:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7976d000'Hello world']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79771790 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7978fce0 V:[UILabel:0x7976d000'Hello world']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79771790 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a081610 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x79771790(568)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7978fce0 V:[UILabel:0x7976d000'Hello world']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79771790 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: You didn't provide frame to label. So it will not display anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add this line it will work

> [label setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

- When using Auto Layout on views created in code, there are a few
  caveats to be aware of. The first is related to the value of the
  property `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. This property is
  YES by default, which means Auto Layout constraints will be created
  based on the view's autoresizing mask. We want the view to respect
  the Auto Layout constraints we will add so this property should be
  set to NO.
- It was old technology that was earlier used for managing view sizes
  You can refer this link [UIView autoresizingMask - Interface Builder to Code - Programmatically create struts and springs - Swift or Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468389/uiview-autoresizingmask-interface-builder-to-code-programmatically-create-st)

> - When this property is YES, which it is by default, the autoresizing    mask of a view is translated into constraints. For example, if a view 
>     is configured as in Figure 6-1 and
>     translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is YES, then the
>     constraints |-20-[button]-20-| and V:|-20-[button(20)] are added to
>     the view’s superview. The net effect is that unaware views behave as
>     they did in versions of OS X prior to 10.7.
>        For views that are aware of Auto Layout, in most circumstances you    will want translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to be NO.
>     This is    because the constraints generated by translating the
>     autoresizing    mask are already sufficient to completely specify the
>     frame of a view    given its superview’s frame, which is generally too
>     much. For    example, this will prevent a button from automatically
>     assuming its    optimal width when its title is changed.

Comment: Thank you, adding that solves my problem. Could you explain about autoresizing mask? I also see it from Apple document but not sure what it is about.

Comment: Thanks Yaiba Glad to help You.

Comment: I can't vote yet but +1 for adding explanation about autoresizing mask (y)